# android menu item doesn't show an image

Tags: android, android-menu

I have this menu layout

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
        android:title="@string/refresh"/>
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/sort_neutral"
        android:title="Sort By Date">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortNewToOld"
                android:icon="@drawable/sort_up"
                android:title="Newest To Oldest"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/sortOldToNew"
                android:icon="@drawable/sort_down"
                android:title="Oldest To Newest"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

the items "@+id/refresh" and "@drawable/sort_neutral" are shown correctly, but the two icons inside the "android:title="Sort By Date" are not shown, I just can see the title of them. any help would be appreciated.

#### note

I am using real mobile song ericsson 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Your icon are probably too large for the menu. Make sure you are using a correct icon size.

Comment: I already used the same image for another menu icons, it is very small